# How to paginate a collection and query builder in laravel

Tags: laravel, performance, vue.js, pagination, inertiajs

I have +30K items in my requests table so i decided to back-end paginate the page showing the requests to user. The problem is that every user does not have permission to see all the requests and it's based on a lot of factors which i made a function that returns whether the user have permission to see a request or not.

The problem is in requests in process i have to pass every request in process to the function to get the permission ( processing request is a small set of items ). So i used the filter function on processing requests and it gives me a collection of 10 items. Now i want to merge the big set of items which is closed requests that can be +10K items with the processing ones and use the paginate feature.

How can i do that ?

This function will explain more what am trying to say :

```
public function getRequests(){
        $closedRequests = request::join('request_logs', 'request_logs.request_id', '=', 'requests.id')
                    ->select("requests.id", "requests.user_id", "requests.form_type", "requests.created_at", "requests.request_status")
                    ->whereNotIn('request_status', [-2, 0])
                    ->where('request_logs.user_id', Auth::user()->id);

        $processingRequests = request::select("requests.id", "requests.user_id", "requests.form_type", "requests.created_at", "requests.request_status")
                         ->where('request_status', 0)
                         ->get()
                         ->filter(function ($request) {
                               return FormsController::checkUserPermissionToConsultForm($request, true);

        });
        $closedRequests = $closedRequests->union($processingRequests)
                            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                            ->paginate(5);
        return $closedRequests;
    }
```

The function above is what i tried to do but it generate an error saying

```
Call to a member function getBindings() on array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a collection and push the items to it, then use then create a class

```php
<?php

namespace App\Support;

use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection as BaseCollection;

class Collection extends BaseCollection
{
    public function paginate($perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page')
    {
        $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);
      
        return new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $this->forPage($page, $perPage),
            $total ?: $this->count(),
            $perPage,
            $page,
            [
                'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                'pageName' => $pageName,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```php
use App\Support\Collection;

$items = [];
$collection = (new Collection($items))->paginate(20);
```

This solution is from a gist I found on github. you can see it [here](https://gist.github.com/simonhamp/549e8821946e2c40a617c85d2cf5af5e)

Comment: After doing that how can i merge the query builder with collection pagination ? the result that am looking for is 1 pagination for both the collection and query builder

Comment: create a new collectoin , push both of them in it. then use the method